# Gitlab run Pipeline if file changed AND its a merge request?

Tags: gitlab-ci

I am trying to build a monorepo with two independent build pipelines. Ideally, they should only run IF files in the projects have changed.  Unfortunately, the both get triggered always and I do not understand why.

My idea is basically:

- run a pipeline: if we are in a merge request AND files relevant to that pipeline have changed
- run a pipeline if we are on the develop or release branch because we want the artifacts

my .gitlab-ci.yml:

```
projectA:
  trigger:
    include: gitlab/ci-projectA.yml
    strategy: depend # fail if the projectAbuild fails
  rules:
    # we want to run this pipeline IF it's a merge request event AND something changed in the relevant filer OR when its on develop OR release branch
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == 'merge_request_event'
      changes:
        paths:
          - projectA.sln
          - projectA/**/*
          - gitlab/ci-projectA.yml
          - .gitlab-ci.yml
      when: on_success
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == "release"
      when: on_success
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == "develop"
      when: on_success
    - when: never
    
project:
  trigger:
    include: gitlab/ci-projectB.yml
    strategy: depend # fail if the projectBbuild fails
  rules:
    # we want to run this pipeline IF it's a merge request event AND something changed in the relevant filer OR when its on develop OR release branch
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == 'merge_request_event'
      changes:
        paths:
          - projectB.sln
          - projectB/**/*
          - gitlab/ci-projectB.yml
          - .gitlab-ci.yml
      when: on_success
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == "release"
      when: on_success
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == "develop"
      when: on_success
    - when: never
```

Comment: Hmm... Looks OK to me, but perhaps I'm misunderstanding the desired behavior. I'm also not sure what scenario, precisely, is producing the problem/unexpected behavior. Could you give concrete examples? In any case, separate rules do not compound (they are logical ORs).  The rules using `$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME` will cause the jobs to run irrespective of the rule for `$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE/changes:` it's not 100% clear to me if that's intentional or not.  Maybe you wanted to combine those conditions into a single `if:` rule OR maybe you want to add the `changes:` clause to each rule.

Comment: @sytech The idea is to run this always when on Develop or Release branch. If it's a MR run it only if something changed in the files.